I'm filling out ds 260 and i have a problem with country/authority that issued my travel documents
I'm filling out DS 260 form and i have a problem with country/authority that issued my passport.  my passport is a Nigerian passport but i got it from Nigerian embassy in cotonou Benin Republic. it's also stated on my passport that authority Cotonou Benin Republic. Please what country should I fill in that issued the passport?

I’m pretty sure it says that the issuing authority is the embassy of Nigeria in Cotonou.

Your passport was issued by the country of Nigeria, using Nigeria's consulte in Cotonou. This question is similar to: Passport "Issued in" vs. "Issuing Country" & "Issuing Authority". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You might also review the comments and answers in this earlier SE:Travel question.

Your passport was issued:

by Nigeria (issuing authority)
in Cotonou (issuing place)

The answer is clearly Nigeria.
